# И еще о язычниках

Tags: этимология

Тут уже поднимался вопрос о происхождении слова "язычник". Но подумалось, ведь в русском языке есть слово "поганый", а оно, видимо, произошло от корня "паган", что тоже означает язычника. Почему тогда негативную окраску приобрело именно слово "поганый", а не "языческий" и откуда оно в русском языке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ПОГАНЫЙ.

Чрезвычайно интересное слово! "Поганус" в Древнем Риме было существительным,
производным от "пагус" - "поле"; значило оно "селянин", "деревенский житель".
Когда в самом Риме, столице государства, уже распространилась новая религия -
христианство, окрестные поселяне - "пагани" - продолжали оставаться заядлыми
язычниками. Слово "паганус" в языке римлян-горожан" приобрело новый смысл,
стало означать "невежда-язычник", "мужлан-язычник", а затем и просто-напросто
"ЯЗЫЧНИК", "нехристианин".
  С распространением новой веры слово это, "паганус", было занесено в Византию,
а оттуда проникло и на Русь. Тут его множественное число - "пагани" -
превратилось в "поганые" и начало обрастать новыми значениями. "Погаными"
стали именовать не только соседей-язычников, в отличие от христиан
("крестьян") - русских; слово распространилось на все, что не одобряла или что
запрещала новая вера.
  Она не допускала в пищу зайчатины, бобрового мяса - эти животные были
признаны "погаными". "Поганым" постепенно стало несъедобное (скажем, ядовитые
грибы - "поганки"; невкусные породы птиц - чомга, или "поганка"), а также и
опасное: "поганик" в языке псковичей - змея-гадюка; да, наконец, и все просто
противное, неприятное. Как видите, от древнеримского "паганус" (земледелец)
до нашего "поганка" (несъедобный гриб) - "дистанция огромного размера". Я бы
советовал в связи с историей слова "поганый" перечесть историю слова
"крестьянин": они являются как бы зеркальными отражениями  одна другой.*

Лев Успенский "Почему не иначе?"